# Do not put the figures into the text file but, instead, indicate their approximate locations directly in the text

Tags: floats

I have recently submitted into a journal and the manuscript is returned with the following comment, "Do not put the figures into the text file but, instead, indicate their approximate locations directly in the text." I am unable to find the detailed meaning of this statement with an example. Is this statement mean that I just have to place all the figures at the end of manuscript?

Comment: If this has come from a journal office you should ask them, but I suspect they mean they want each figure as an independent file with just 'FIGURE X NEAR HERE' in the manuscript.

Answer (score 1):

Typically journals want figures as separate files. In practice you can put them at the back of the file with a note in the text stating where they belong. If you use the endfloat package it will do both of these things for you automatically.

Comment: Btw, endfloat does not work with the elsarticle document class (Elsevier journal papers class). Trying to use it spawns a heap of errors on compilation.